# Delete/undelete protocol: bug or by design?

Tags: support

I deleted my own answer to this question: [Does the Quran say in its verse 4:89 that "Those who reject Islam must be killed"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36428/does-the-quran-say-those-who-reject-islam-must-be-killed) while the question was on IslamSE .

Then my answer was somehow undeleted by someone else or some algorithm and the whole history of the question being migrated, repatriated, and my answer being deleted and undeleted were erased, as well as my comment about why I was deleting my answer.

At this point, I don't really mind that my answer was undeleted, but I think it would be better if there was an edit history that showed that the answer was deleted by me, and then undeleted by someone else or by a program.

My question then is was my answer undelete by human or algorithm? and was the undeletion process by-design or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer was never undeleted. The migrated question on Islam is a copy of the original question on Skeptics. When the migration is rejected, the original question here was simply unlocked, and on that question your answer was never deleted.

Migration creates a copy of the question on the target site and locks the original question on the source site. If the question is closed on the target site, it is locked there and the copy on the original site is unlocked.

Rejected migrations can easily be confusing if you don't know how the whole process is actually implemented (knowledge which a regular user doesn't need). But I don't really see a good way to improve this case that doesn't involve removing migrations entirely, or fundamentally changing the way they work behind the scenes.

Comment: Now it's back to being deleted.  Very confusing.

Comment: @DavePhD: An hour after than comment, I see it as undeleted! At this point I am too scared to delete it for you, because I don't know what your desired state is.

Comment: @Odddthinking Actually, now when I look at it from my phone it's deleted and when I look from my desktop it is undeleted. Both show very updated information such as your above comment. I don't really care if this particular answer is deleted or undeleted, I'm just trying to understand what's happening.